# Обработчик события: как узнать выбранный пункт меню?

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

Я создаю динамически пункты меню "ПОРТЫ", которые формируются в зависимости от количества открытых СОМ портов. Соответственно, для всех пунктов меню СОМ1, ... СОМх один обработчик события (`сMenuItem.Click += ComMenuItem_Click;`)
Как правильно в обработчике

```
private void ComMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //?   
}
```

отловить именно тот пункт, который был выбран?

Answer (score 3):

Это делается через `sender`:

```
private void ComMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    // Дальше делаем ещё что-то.   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Коллеги!
Все оказалось просто! Спасибо за Ваше время.

```
 private void ComMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           string msg = ((MenuItem)sender).Name;
           MessageBox.Show(msg);
        }
```

Comment: Поставьте зеленую галочку тому, кто вам помог, ему будет приятно